# Trigger a Bootstrap Modal Pop-up from Code-behind not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

Good day!

I have been following [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2059944.aspx?Trigger%20a%20Bootstrap%20Modal%20Pop%20up%20from%20Code%20behind%20of%20Site%20Master) post for launching a bootstrap modal popup from my code behind but unfortunately it is not working.

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

**Button**

```
<asp:LinkButton class="alert alert-warning" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateItem_click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'   >Update</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void UpdateItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    }
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                        data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">title
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Username_Update" CssClass="form-control" />
                       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="bookId2" CssClass="form-control" />
                    <input type="text" runat="server" id="Username_Update2" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                        close
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
```

Instead of using a `Button` just like from the post, I used a `LinkButton` because I wanted a certain value to be passed in my code behind then select all data needed and populate the modal which will then be launched using this code behind code.

Unfortunately, the modal is not showing and I have no idea whether the code is working properly or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have found the problem. I found out(with the help of a colleague) that my button's OnClick function was not working. Since I have a Validator in my page, I've tried adding each button with this code `CausesValidation="false"` and now the code works perfectly.